# MongoDB GridFS find file by ID

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, gridfs

I am using MongoDB GridFS to store files. 
I am trying to implement solution to be able to find files by name AND ID

Finding file and returning is pretty straightforward.

```
$bucket = DB::getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStreamByName('file_name.pdf', ['revision' => 0]);
contents = stream_get_contents($stream);

return response($contents)
->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
->header('Content-Disposition',  'attachment; filename="file_name.pdf"');
```

How can achieve the same thing when searching file by ID, in cases when I will know only file ID  (for example: 5d89ff86740f35501419d7f2)?

Comment: `openDownloadStream()` selects by `id` see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBGridFSBucket-openDownloadStream/)

Comment: Yes, This worked. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use `openDownloadStream` to select a file by its `id`.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBGridFSBucket-openDownloadStream/):

```
MongoDB\GridFS\Bucket::openDownloadStream
```

> Selects a GridFS file by its _id and opens it as a readable stream.

So in your case something like this:

```
$bucket = DB::getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$stream = $bucket->openDownloadStream('5d89ff86740f35501419d7f2');
```